# C# Printing Properties

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class like this with a bunch of properties:

```
class ClassName
{
     string Name {get; set;}
     int Age {get; set;}
     DateTime BirthDate {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to print the name of the property and it's value using the value's ToString() method and the Property's name like this:

```
ClassName cn = new ClassName() {Name = "Mark", Age = 428, BirthData = DateTime.Now}
cn.MethodToPrint();

// Output
// Name = Mark, Age = 428, BirthDate = 12/30/2010 09:20:23 PM
```

Reflection is perfectly okay, in fact I think it is probably required.  I'd also be neat if it could somehow work on any class through some sort of inheritance.  I'm using 4.0 if that matters.

Comment: Go for it.  Next time try asking a question.

Comment: @Hans: How do I write code that produces the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you mentioned, you can accomplish this with reflection. Make sure you're `using System.Reflection`.

```
public void Print()
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        object value = prop.GetValue(this, new object[] { });
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd replace `typeof(ClassName)` with `this.GetType()`.

Comment: Good call, I've updated my answer with that, and to work with public/private properties.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is `typeof(ClassName).GetProperties()`. This will give you an array of `PropertyInfo` objects, each of which has a `Name` property as well as a `GetValue` method.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only going to use this class, you can override the ToString method, like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Name = {1}, Age = {2}, BirthDate= {3}", Name, Age, BirthData.ToLongTimeString());
}
```

If you need to represent only that class, then this would be the solution. You can do something like

```
ClassName jhon = ....
Console.WriteLine(jhon);
```